# 2011 Nissan Altima's CVT is on the verge of dying - can the car be pushed in Neutral with Engine running

Tags: cvt-transmission

My 2011 Nissan Altima's CVT is slipping very badly.  In essence, it's almost close to death.  I live 3 miles from my shade tree mechanic who I respect & trust.  He indicated that the car has so many miles on it (i.e., over 170,000) that it's not cost effective to replace the CVT.  The car is at his place and he'd like for me to get it.

Since I don't care what happens to the CVT and will be selling the car for parts or selling the whole car to a Junk Yard, my question is this:  can the car be pushed by another vehicle to my house if I turn the car on and put it in neutral.

Note the engine still works, and it actually may be able to be driven at slow speeds.  I ask the question - as my buddy will be following me home in his car, and should the CVT completely die I want to make sure he can push my car back to my place.

Comment: Bumper pushing has been covered already. It's a bad idea. Personally I would get a second opinion before scrapping a car, even if I trust the mechanic.